# Selenium in Jupyter Notebook, Different Outcome on Different Cells

Tags: python, selenium, jupyter-notebook

I'm a student studying Python and Web Crawling in Korea.

I found something I can't understand why. I want to ask why this happens and how can I fix it.

It will lovely if someone is gonna help me.

Here is my situation:

This is a code for my web crawling. There is some Korean words, but that's not important, I think.

```
zeropay_official = 'https://www.zeropay.or.kr/main.do?pgmId=PGM0081'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./driver/chromedriver')
driver.get(zeropay_official)
driver.find_element_by_id('tryCode').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('tryCode').send_keys('서울특별시')
driver.find_element_by_id('skkCode').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('skkCode').send_keys('노원구')
driver.find_element_by_id('pobsAfstrName').send_keys('다마식당')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form"]/div[2]/a').click()
test = driver.find_element_by_id('list_div')
test.text
```

and right below this Jupyter Notebook cell, I put the last line of the code,

```
test.text
```

to check what's happening.

But, first cell's output ls ''(None), and second cell's output is some string which I wanted to get.

Why Is this happening? And if I need to get the output data string on the first cell, to make this code as a module so my team can import it, what should I do?

[Check this image if you couldn't clearly understand what I said due to my poor English.(sob)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql31g.png)

Comment: Why would you `send_keys()` to a `<select>` tag?

Comment: If you add some wait time and try.

Comment: @DebanjanB send_keys() to a <select> tag? I didn't get it... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some wait time.

```
zeropay_official = 'https://www.zeropay.or.kr/main.do?pgmId=PGM0081'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./driver/chromedriver')
driver.get(zeropay_official)
driver.find_element_by_id('tryCode').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('tryCode').send_keys('서울특별시')
driver.find_element_by_id('skkCode').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('skkCode').send_keys('노원구')
driver.find_element_by_id('pobsAfstrName').send_keys('다마식당')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form"]/div[2]/a').click()
time.sleep(time_in_seconds)
test = driver.find_element_by_id('list_div')
test.text
```

As Korean text is taking some time to appear.